# Play store reports “Your device isn't compatible with this version” but it installs via adb just fine on onePlus

Tags: android

I have an app I released to a private Google Play beta. I can install this exact same APK to my oneplus 6 and 7 just fine with

adb pm install

but through the Google Play store it is marked for this exact same oneplus7 as

Your device isn't compatible with this version.

This is the same apk. I can't figure out how to get any information on why the play store thinks it's not compatible.

My manifest looks like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.w" 
android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" 
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Any help on determining why Google Play thinks it is not compatible?

Comment: show full manifest and also build.gradle

Comment: <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launch_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/> other is activity tags.

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "infotel.PrekshaMeditation"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 20030034
        versionName "3.1.15"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false

Comment: please edit question and add it to question, format it as code instead of addig to comments

Comment: please help me out.

Comment: sure, but first `please edit question and add it to question, format it as code instead of addig to comments` as I wrote